# Locking with Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I'm really getting confused how locking works in Obj-C.

I simply have a network request which I only want to call once at the same time. I want to block all other calls to it until it has received some data.

My `lock` is of type `NSCondition` and static, `_sending` is just a bool. This is my implementation. The `getWithSuccess` is using `AFNetworking` for perform some action network requests, so I think it can start multiple threads or using some magic in GDC.

My problem is that this implementation just give me deadlocks, and I need some hint how a correct implementation should work.

```
[lock lock];

while (_sending)
    [lock wait];

_sending = YES;

[self getWithSuccess:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    _sending = NO;

    [lock signal];
    [lock unlock];


} fail:^() {
    _sending = NO;

    [lock signal];
    [lock unlock];
}];
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever put a while loop around `-wait`.

Comment: I'm a real noob on thi, so sorry if I don't get it right. I just tried to remove the while statement. But that's just make my code freeze. Should I change order of something more?

Comment: You can't use that kind of locking with a single-threaded asynchronous API.  The second incoming request will block the thread as it waits to acquire the lock, preventing the success/fail response handlers from executing.

Comment: @Darren It was unclear for me that the GDC was running on a single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've accomplished something similar to this using `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`. Depending on your needs, you can subclass `NSOperation` and check if an operation of that type is in the queue before adding a new one (to prevent duplicate calls) or just put your network requests in the queue and they will execute in order, one at a time by setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1

You mentioned you are using AFNetworking which has an NSOperation subclass called AFURLConnectionOperation that might suit your needs as well.